# Norm of the gradient of a Lipschitz function

Tags: partial-derivative, lipschitz-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable Lipschitz function with Lipschitz constant $K$. Is it true that, ${\|\nabla f(x)\|}_2\leq K$, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, where $\nabla f(x)$ denotes vector of partial derivatives of $f$ at $x$. I get an upper bound, but cannot make it free of $n$. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

By differentiability
$$
\nabla f(x)^Th = f(x+h)-f(x) + o(h),
$$
so
$$
|\nabla f(x)^Th| \le |f(x+h) - f(x)| + |o(h)| \le K \|h\|_2 + |o(h)|.
$$
Fix $h$ with $\|h\|_2=1$, replace $h$ in the above formula by $th$, $t>0$, then divide by $t$ to get
$$
|\nabla f(x)^Th| \le K  + t^{-1} |o(th)|,
$$
now passing to the limit $t\searrow0$ proves 
$$
|\nabla f(x)^Th| \le K
$$
for all $h$ with $\|h\|_2=1$, which implies the claim.

Comment: why $t^{-1} |o(th)|$ becomes zero when t goes to 0? also shouldn't we give an explicit h for the last claim? for example if we set $h = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt(n)}$ we get an extra n.